# Uncomment block of lines in a file

Tags: sed

```
-- *****************************************************************************
-- ** Storage group name                         = IBMSTOGROUP
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- *****************************************************************************
-- SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP
-- ON '/udb/ss/DI10'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI9'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI8'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI7'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI6'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI5'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI4'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI3'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI2'
-- ,  '/udb/ss/DI1'
-- ;
```

Need to replace `--` with `''`.

I used sed command but it is displaying twice.

```
 sed -n "/-- ON/,/DI1.*$/c\ON '/udb/ss/DI1','/udb/ss/DI2','/udb/ss/DI3'/" file
```

I need to replace -- with ''.

**Expected Output:**

```bash
-- *****************************************************************************
-- ** Storage group name                         = IBMSTOGROUP
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- *****************************************************************************
SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP
ON '/udb/ss/DI10'
,  '/udb/ss/DI9'
,  '/udb/ss/DI8'
,  '/udb/ss/DI7'
,  '/udb/ss/DI6'
,  '/udb/ss/DI5'
,  '/udb/ss/DI4'
,  '/udb/ss/DI3'
,  '/udb/ss/DI2'
,  '/udb/ss/DI1'
;
```

Comment: Can you please show what the desired output is?

Comment: -- ** Storage group name                         = IBMSTOGROUP
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- *****************************************************************************
 SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP
 ON '/udb/ss/DI10'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI9'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI8'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI7'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI6'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI5'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI4'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI3'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI2'
 ,  '/udb/ss/DI1'
 ;
-- *****************************************************************************
-- ** Storage group name

Comment: @gowri: There is an `edit` link below your question that can be used to edit details in your question (I just did it for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` command to remove comments in a block from `SET` line to `;` line:

```bash
sed -E '/^-- *SET/,/^-- *;/ s/^-- *//' file

-- *****************************************************************************
-- ** Storage group name                         = IBMSTOGROUP
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- *****************************************************************************
SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP
ON '/udb/ss/DI10'
,  '/udb/ss/DI9'
,  '/udb/ss/DI8'
,  '/udb/ss/DI7'
,  '/udb/ss/DI6'
,  '/udb/ss/DI5'
,  '/udb/ss/DI4'
,  '/udb/ss/DI3'
,  '/udb/ss/DI2'
,  '/udb/ss/DI1'
;
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^-- *SET/,/^-- *;/`: Match a range of lines starting from `-- SET` to `-- ;` line
- `s/^-- *//`: Remove `--` followed by 0 or more spaces at the line start